# How to pass texture to Metal's fragment shader with SCNProgram?

Tags: scenekit, metal

When using SCNProgram with Metal, how do we pass a texture to the fragment shader ? do we use SCNProgram's handleBindingOfBufferNamed ? If so, can someone provide an example of how ? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with `SCNMaterialProperty`. On the same `SCNMaterial` where you set your custom program object, you can use key-value coding to set a value for a fragment texture by parameter name:

```
[material setProgram:program];

SCNMaterialProperty *materialProperty = [SCNMaterialProperty materialPropertyWithContents:image];
[material setValue:materialProperty forKey:@"fragmentTextureName"];
```

`image` can be an `NSImage` or `UIImage`, depending on your platform. The image will be bound as a texture with the corresponding parameter name, and you can read or sample from it in your custom fragment function.

Comment: Can you provide a short snippet of how you can use fragmentTextureName in your fragment shader?